# How to solve a system of two differential equations $\dot y = x, \dot x = y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

What I've done so far is:

$\dot y = \ddot x$ $\Rightarrow \ddot x - x = 0$ $\Rightarrow x = C_1 e^{-t} + C_2 e^{t}$

If I've done this right so far, how do I get the solution for $y$ out of this? If not, what is the correct procedure?

Comment: $y=\dot{x} = -C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^t$

Comment: Then you report in the initial system of equations. Calculate $y=\dot x$, and then tune the constants so that $\dot y=x$. In this case, no tuning in necessary.

Comment: The result of @Kenny Lau can as well be written as a linear combination of $\cosh(t)$ and $\sinh(t)$. It is important to underline that $y$ for example obeys $y''=y$, which is similar to $y''=-y$ (harmonic oscillator) whose general solution is (any) linear combination of $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ (hyperbolic trigonometry in one case and circular trigonometry in the other).